# Unity launcher shows blacklisted unmounted partitions forever

Tags: unity, launcher, gparted

"unlock from launcher" is ineffective - they all come back with the next boot.

There is a workaround posted for Ubuntu 12.10 (see below) but this does not work for 15.04. This started after using gparted.

Is there a fix or workaround?

[Partitions unlocked from Unity launcher show up again after starting gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/246956/partitions-unlocked-from-unity-launcher-show-up-again-after-starting-gparted)

Comment: Please tell us what do you want to achieve? Get partitions not shown at all?

Comment: To create a fix: once your system runs (after startup), do you unmount/remount, or are the drives/partitions mounted all the time? It can be fixed, but the measure to be taken depends. Please let me know.

Comment: Michael, are you looking for a solution or is the question abandoned?

Comment: Jacob, here is the sequence: (1) reboot and log in. (2) all unmounted partitions show up in launcher list. (3) for all of them, right click and select "unlock from launcher". (4) they go away as they should. (5) log out and log in. (6) they are still gone as they should be. (7) reboot and log in. (8) they all come back.

Comment: I created an administrator account and put all disks on the blacklist from there. No change. All disks (partitions) come back after a reboot.

Answer (score 1):

At least I found what the trigger for this is:
   Gnome disk utility `/usr/bin/gnome-disks`.

If a standby timeout or APM is activated for any drive, it causes the launchers for all unmounted partitions to be shown. This misbehavior was recently introduced.

I fixed it by turning off APM.

Comment: Did you see my comment(s) on the question?

Comment: I reviewed your comments just now, and I am not sure what you want. The partitions are all unmounted and stay that way. That seems to be irrelevant to the problem. I think the solution is to fix the bug in gnome-disk-utility. When it starts (after every reboot), adds the partitions to the launcher even if they are not mounted and are blacklisted. And this only if APM or standby timeout is activated. It did not used to do this.

Comment: I can't fix a bug for you, but I can fix its effect. Blacklisted items are blacklisted until restart, that is what is happening.

Comment: Then please explain why other launchers for other partitions stay blacklisted over a restart. Only the disk with APM turned on has partitions that come back eternally. I fixed this by turning APM off. Now the partitioins stay blacklisted, also over a restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup /etc/fstab a way that all partitions are mount somewhere (not /media or its subdirectories), then they will be never shown at the launcher.

You can find how to setup fstab [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab)